Difficult Exercises on Abstract Algebra
Could someone please suggest me a book or set of difficult and educational exercises covering Groups, Rings and Fields. Preferably with solutions.

The answer depends on the level you're targeting. What is it?

Undergraduate level. So maybe up to Sylow Theorems, UFDs, Field Extensions. By difficult I mean any exercise which would require a clear understanding/ some thought rather than something that follow directly from a theorem/dfn
